# How to split a large number into pairs and compare?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a function without using any imports that takes in a number like 
`(12345643)` and groups it into pairs so it is 
`[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]`

Comment: Do you know how to extract digits from a number? Also, your algorithm basically finds the largest digit of a number, and you don't need to group them in pairs - just use the `max` built-in function.

Comment: I forgot to include that if the number is paired up with [7,7] then it doesn't count and moves on to the next pair and if there isn't a pair, it is a lone number that gets compared with the rest of the numbers.

Comment: As a starting point: `f = lambda num:[(str(num)[a], str(num)[a+1]) for a in range(0,len(str(num)),2)]` gives you a function that creates a list of your pairs. I deleted my answer again because that would have required more explanation to be worthy of being called an answer

Comment: @ChargedUp1 Please don't ask a complete coding task here. Instead, find out the specific things you do not understand and ask about each one seperately if it has not yet been answered on stackoverflow

Comment: then, i just changed the question on how to get them into pairs. thanks

Comment: Use merge sort and compare with pairs of 2 ignoring pairs that are equal. You can find an example implementation here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/

Answer (score 1):

```
_num=123456123

max([int(i) for i in str(_num)])
```

will find the largest singular digit.

Comment: Elegant, and helps absolutely nothing for understanding of OP. I gave +1 because I find it funny, but I also deleted my own answer because the OP is asking for work instead of explanations

Comment: please don't use built-in functions (input) as a varibale name.

Comment: that's fair @Psytho I was moving quickly and got careless, editing to remove that

Answer (score 1):

To 'split' your number into the pairs, you can use the modulus and divide operations.
See an example below

`12345643 % 10 = 3
12345643 / 10 = 1234564`

You can simply iterate over it while it is bigger than 0 to obtain every single digit.
The following part shouldn't be too difficult, feel free to ask if you find any issue with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def pares(n):
    vector_final = []
    pares = []
    for x in str(n):
        if len(pares) < 2:
            pares.append(int(x))
        else:
            vector_final.append(pares)
            pares = []
            pares.append(int(x))
    if len(pares) > 0:
        vector_final.append(pares)
    return vector_final


def compara(vector):
    numero = ""
    for v in vector:
        numero = numero + str(max(v))
    return numero


numero = 1234567890

while len(str(numero)) != 1:
    vector = pares(numero)
    numero = compara(vector)

print("respuesta final =>", numero)
```